# Defined Step in Webdriver generates an Undefined step?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

Considering the following Gherkin Scenario:

```
  Scenario: This is a scenario 001
    Given The user opens "website"
    Then waits a few seconds
```

The first step goes OK: webdriver opens a browser and navigates to the start URL. Then, this happens:

```
  Undefined step: Then  waits a few seconds
```

Out of the blue, the step definition **creates an extra space** for no apparent reason... The java code looks like this:

```
    @Then("^waits a few seconds$")
public void WaitsAFewSeconds() throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
}
```

Who can tell me where this extra space is coming from??

Additional info: 
- Normally, I write the Gherkin Code first, and press ALT+ENTER in IntelliJ to create the step definition. The steps for both gherkin lines are both present in the step definition file.